# How to grep an xml block in an xml file using a keyword in ksh

Tags: bash, shell, regular-expression, ksh, xml

I have a file Sample.xml which contains a lot of services inside it 
and the structure looks like this

Notes:

1. I cannot use any XML parser tool as I don't have permission, read only
2. My xmllint version does not support xpath, and I cannot update it, read only
3. I don't have xmlstarlet and cannot install it

PROBLEM: 
INPUT: QUEUE NAME

OUTPUT: SERVICE BLOCK

sample 
INPUT: ABC.getme2

OUTPUT NEEDED:

```
<service name="GETME2" min="1" max="10" idleTime="300" backend="ABC">
                            <handlerContainer className="com.abc.xyz.wqere.abcqwere">
                            <handler className="com.abc.xyz.qweqweqwe.werwerwerwer"/>
                            </handlerContainer>
                            <mqListener queue="ABC.getme2" suggExpiry="30" minExpiry="4" maxExpiry="500" copyMessageId="true"/>
                    </service>
```

XML Structure:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <deploymentconfig xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <configfile>sample.xml</configfile>
                <exceptionsFilterConfigFile>asdasd.xml</exceptionsFilterConfigFile>
                <keyInfoConfigFile>asdasd.xml</keyInfoConfigFile>
                <services>

    <service name="GETME" min="1" max="10" idleTime="300" backend="ABC">
                            <handlerContainer className="com.abc.xyz.wqere.abcqwere">
                            <handler className="com.abc.xyz.qweqweqwe.werwerwerwer"/>
                            </handlerContainer>
                            <mqListener queue="ABC.getme" suggExpiry="30" minExpiry="4" maxExpiry="500" copyMessageId="true"/>
                    </service>

    <service name="GETME2" min="1" max="10" idleTime="300" backend="ABC">
                            <handlerContainer className="com.abc.xyz.wqere.abcqwere">
                            <handler className="com.abc.xyz.qweqweqwe.werwerwerwer"/>
                            </handlerContainer>
                            <mqListener queue="ABC.getme2" suggExpiry="30" minExpiry="4" maxExpiry="500" copyMessageId="true"/>
                    </service>
        . . . .a lot of services like this . . . .
        . . . .a lot of services like this . . . .
        . . . .a lot of services like this . . . .
        . . . .a lot of services like this . . . .
        </services>
   <batchServices>
                        <batchService name="batch1">
                                <executor className="com.abc.xyz.qwer.qweqwewqe.ffdsdfsdfsdfsdf" />
                        </batchService>
                        <batchService name="batch2">
                                <executor className="com.abc.xyz.qwer.qweqwewqe.zxcsadsad" />
                        </batchService>
. . . .a lot of batch services like this . . . .
        . . . .a lot of batch services like this . . . .
        . . . .a lot of batch services like this . . . .
        . . . .a lot of batch services like this . . . .
      </batchServices>

<timerservices>
<timerservice> - a lot of timeservice
</timerservices>

  <connectionPools>
                <pool>
                        <name>asdasd</name>
                        <driver>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driver>
                        <url>$asdasd_URL</url>
                        <userId>$asdasd_USER</userId>
                        <password>$asdasd_PASSWORD</password>
                        <minConnections>0</minConnections>
                        <maxConnections>10</maxConnections>
                        <poolUrl>jdbc:asdsad:asdasdsad</poolUrl>
                        <testSql>select * from abc</testSql>
                </pool>

 . . a lot of pools. . .

</connectionpools>

</deploymentconfig>
```

I need to grep an xml block like this:

```
 <service name="GETME" min="1" max="10" idleTime="300" backend="ABC">
                        <handlerContainer className="com.abc.xyz.wqere.abcqwere">
                        <handler className="com.abc.xyz.qweqweqwe.werwerwerwer"/>
                        </handlerContainer>
                        <mqListener queue="ABC.getme" suggExpiry="30" minExpiry="4" maxExpiry="500" copyMessageId="true"/>
                </service>
```

and I only need to provide the queue name

```
QUEUENAME=INSERT_HERE
grep ______________ $QUEUENAME. . .
```

Here is the output:

```
Usage : xmllint [options] XMLfiles ...
    Parse the XML files and output the result of the parsing
    --version : display the version of the XML library used
    --debug : dump a debug tree of the in-memory document
    --shell : run a navigating shell
    --debugent : debug the entities defined in the document
    --copy : used to test the internal copy implementation
    --recover : output what was parsable on broken XML documents
    --noent : substitute entity references by their value
    --noout : don't output the result tree
    --path 'paths': provide a set of paths for resources
    --load-trace : print trace of all external entites loaded
    --nonet : refuse to fetch DTDs or entities over network
    --nocompact : do not generate compact text nodes
    --htmlout : output results as HTML
    --nowrap : do not put HTML doc wrapper
    --valid : validate the document in addition to std well-formed check
    --postvalid : do a posteriori validation, i.e after parsing
    --dtdvalid URL : do a posteriori validation against a given DTD
    --dtdvalidfpi FPI : same but name the DTD with a Public Identifier
    --timing : print some timings
    --output file or -o file: save to a given file
    --repeat : repeat 100 times, for timing or profiling
    --insert : ad-hoc test for valid insertions
    --compress : turn on gzip compression of output
    --html : use the HTML parser
    --xmlout : force to use the XML serializer when using --html
    --push : use the push mode of the parser
    --memory : parse from memory
    --maxmem nbbytes : limits memory allocation to nbbytes bytes
    --nowarning : do not emit warnings from parser/validator
    --noblanks : drop (ignorable?) blanks spaces
    --nocdata : replace cdata section with text nodes
    --format : reformat/reindent the input
    --encode encoding : output in the given encoding
    --dropdtd : remove the DOCTYPE of the input docs
    --c14n : save in W3C canonical format (with comments)
    --exc-c14n : save in W3C exclusive canonical format (with comments)
    --nsclean : remove redundant namespace declarations
    --testIO : test user I/O support
    --catalogs : use SGML catalogs from $SGML_CATALOG_FILES
                 otherwise XML Catalogs starting from 
             file:///etc/xml/catalog are activated by default
    --nocatalogs: deactivate all catalogs
    --auto : generate a small doc on the fly
    --xinclude : do XInclude processing
    --noxincludenode : same but do not generate XInclude nodes
    --loaddtd : fetch external DTD
    --dtdattr : loaddtd + populate the tree with inherited attributes 
    --stream : use the streaming interface to process very large files
    --walker : create a reader and walk though the resulting doc
    --pattern pattern_value : test the pattern support
    --chkregister : verify the node registration code
    --relaxng schema : do RelaxNG validation against the schema
    --schema schema : do validation against the WXS schema
    --schematron schema : do validation against a schematron
    --sax1: use the old SAX1 interfaces for processing
    --sax: do not build a tree but work just at the SAX level

Libxml project home page: http://xmlsoft.org/
To report bugs or get some help check: http://xmlsoft.org/bugs.html
```

Here is the version

```
xmllint: using libxml version 20626
```

Comment: Take a look at xmllint or xmlstarlet.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "grep an xml block like this..." Are you looking for a specific block by service name, but want to print the entire block? Or do you want to get the name fields of every service? (`awk` would probably work better in either case, since grep is line-oriented.)

Comment: I just want to print the entire block of the service name

Comment: Could you provide the exact xml input file? Atleast the exact structure of your xml file is  required to provide you a `xmllint` code that would work.

Comment: @shivams The xml file composes of a bunch of the sample block I posted in the question

Comment: So, there is no other parent of these blocks in the xml?

Comment: <services> <service> </service> </services>

Comment: @PhilipMorris See my answer according to an assumed xml file.

Comment: Sample XML is useful, but please resist the temptation to include `more like this` comments - it invalidates the XML. If your XML doesn't have matched start/end tags, it's not valid, and can't be parsed as XML. And that includes `<connectionPools>` closing with `</connectionPools>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the conditions:

1. I cannot use any XML parser tool as I don't have permission , read only
2. My xmllint version does not support xpath, and I cannot update it , read only
3. I dont have xmlstarlet and cannot install it

I resorted to finding other unconventional solutions. This awk command got me what I needed

```
awk '
  /<service.*name=/ { f=1 ; m=0 ; res="" }
  f { res = res $0 ORS }
  f && /mqListener queue="ABC.getme2"/ { m=1 }
  /<\/service>/ { f=0 ; if (m) print res $0 }
' Sample.xml
```

Special thanks to @Janis for helping me here -[How to implement awk range pattern in fetching an xml block when the input parameter is in the middle of the block](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207142/how-to-implement-awk-range-pattern-in-fetching-an-xml-block-when-the-input-param/207159?noredirect=1#comment349851_207159)

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the above comment, `xmllint` can be used like

```
xmllint --xpath '//service/[@name="GETME"]' Sample.xml
```

The option is available at least as of libxml version 20903.

A primer on xpath syntax can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp or more authoritatively https://www.w3.org/Consortium/Offices/Presentations/XSLT_XPATH/#(23)

Comment: Im getting Unknown option --xpath

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the *latest* `ksh` - by which I mean a recent build of `ksh93` - you can actually just use it. `ksh93` supports *compound* variable types - which are a little like a C struct - or an XML node-tree. It doesn't natively support XML at the moment - though I believe that it is planned - but it does support `json` right now.

I used some [free online converter](http://www.freeformatter.com/xml-to-json-converter.html#ad-output) thing to get a `json` output of your sample. Still though, after cleaning up your sample a little *(the **p** in **</connectionpools>** should be upper-cased, by the way)* I could do:

```
print -j queue.services.[@name]
```

...and was rewarded with...

```
GETME
```

I could also do:

```
print -j queue.services[1].[@name]
```

...to get instead...

```
GETME2
```

At the linked conversion site I had to select *Tab-delimited* to keep it from sticking in a lot of non-breaking spaces, but other than that it seems to have come off ok. Surely there are tools you can use as easily to locally to do similar conversions.

In any case, with `ksh` you can read in a `json` tree after copying it to your clipboard just like I did, like:

```
read -m json queue <<<"$(xsel -bo)"
```

After doing that I could view the whole structure like...

```
print -j queue
```

...which printed...

```
{
    "batchServices": [
        {
            "@name": "batch1",
            "executor": {
                "@className": "com.abc.xyz.qwer.qweqwewqe.ffdsdfsdfsdfsdf"
            }
        },
        {
            "@name": "batch2",
            "executor": {
                "@className": "com.abc.xyz.qwer.qweqwewqe.zxcsadsad"
            }
        }
    ],
    "configfile": "sample.xml",
    "connectionPools": [
        {
            "driver": "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver",
            "maxConnections": "10",
            "minConnections": "0",
            "name": "asdasd",
            "password": "$asdasd_PASSWORD",
            "poolUrl": "jdbc:asdsad:asdasdsad",
            "testSql": "select * from abc",
            "url": "$asdasd_URL",
            "userId": "$asdasd_USER"
        }
    ],
    "exceptionsFilterConfigFile": "asdasd.xml",
    "keyInfoConfigFile": "asdasd.xml",
    "services": [
        {
            "@backend": "ABC",
            "@idleTime": "300",
            "@max": "10",
            "@min": "1",
            "@name": "GETME",
            "handlerContainer": {
                "@className": "com.abc.xyz.wqere.abcqwere",
                "handler": {
                    "@className": "com.abc.xyz.qweqweqwe.werwerwerwer"
                }
            },
            "mqListener": {
                "@copyMessageId": "true",
                "@maxExpiry": "500",
                "@minExpiry": "4",
                "@queue": "ABC.getme",
                "@suggExpiry": "30"
            }
        },
        {
            "@backend": "ABC",
            "@idleTime": "300",
            "@max": "10",
            "@min": "1",
            "@name": "GETME2",
            "handlerContainer": {
                "@className": "com.abc.xyz.wqere.abcqwere",
                "handler": {
                    "@className": "com.abc.xyz.qweqweqwe.werwerwerwer"
                }
            },
            "mqListener": {
                "@copyMessageId": "true",
                "@maxExpiry": "500",
                "@minExpiry": "4",
                "@queue": "ABC.getme2",
                "@suggExpiry": "30"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a sample xml file like this:

```
<services>

 <service name="GETME" min="1" max="10" idleTime="300" backend="ABC">
                        <handlerContainer className="com.abc.xyz.wqere.abcqwere">
                        <handler className="com.abc.xyz.qweqweqwe.werwerwerwer"/>
                        </handlerContainer>
                        <mqListener queue="ABC.sadasdasd" suggExpiry="30" minExpiry="4" maxExpiry="500" copyMessageId="true"/>
  </service>

  <service name="GETHIM" min="1" max="10" idleTime="300" backend="ABC">
                        <handlerContainer className="com.abc.xyz.wqere.abcqwere">
                        <handler className="com.abc.xyz.qweqweqwe.werwerwerwer"/>
                        </handlerContainer>
                        <mqListener queue="ABC.sadasdasd" suggExpiry="30" minExpiry="4" maxExpiry="500" copyMessageId="true"/>
  </service>

</services>
```

#### Solution using `xmlstarlet`

The solution to extract the `queue` value of service with `name` as `GETME` is as following:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v "/services/service[@name='GETME']/mqListener/@queue" test.xml
```

Here,

```
-t  ==>  select template 
-v  ==>  template selected is "value", i.e. value-of <xpath>
```

#### Solution using `xmllint`

```
xmllint --xpath "/services/service[@name='GETME']/mqListener/@queue" test.xml
```

Comment: neither worked. I posted a more elaborate xml structure. And I need queue name as input and the service block as my output

Comment: -ksh: xmlstarlet: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: in xmllint, Unknown option --xpath
Usage : xmllint [options] XMLfiles ...

Comment: You will need to install `xmlstarlet` from your package manager. On Ubuntu, you could install it by `sudo  apt-get install xmlstarlet`.

Comment: I dont have permissions =(

Answer (score 0):

OK, first and foremost - don't use `grep`. XML is not a suitable format for regex based parsing. Use an XML parser instead.

My favourite XML Parser is actually a `perl` module called [`XML::Twig`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Twig).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my ($keyword, $filename) = @ARGV;

XML::Twig->new(
    'pretty_print'  => 'indented_a',
    'twig_handlers' => {
        'service[@name="'.$keyword.'"]' => sub { $_->print }
    }
)->parsefile($filename);
```

Invoked with `myscript.pl GETME yourxml` it will print any matches. (Change `pretty_print` to a format you like).

`XML::Twig` actually comes bundled with a couple of sample use cases too, such as `xml_grep` too, which probably does a lot of what you want anyway.

With your example XML above (slightly hacked, because it's not valid, and I've *assumed* that your source XML actually is, and this is a transposition error).

```
<service
        backend="ABC"
        idleTime="300"
        max="10"
        min="1"
        name="GETME">
      <handlerContainer className="com.abc.xyz.wqere.abcqwere">
        <handler className="com.abc.xyz.qweqweqwe.werwerwerwer" />
      </handlerContainer>
      <mqListener
          copyMessageId="true"
          maxExpiry="500"
          minExpiry="4"
          queue="ABC.getme"
          suggExpiry="30"
      />
    </service>
```

NB: This format is `indented_a` in `XML::Twig`. Others are available. This is at least partly an illustration of why regular expression and line based matching of XML is dangerous.

Comment: This is the output :$ use strict;
-ksh: use: not found [No such file or directory]
$ use warnings;
-ksh: use: not found [No such file or directory]
$
$ use XML::Twig;
-ksh: use: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: ... no, it wouldn't be found in `ksh` because it's a perl script.

Comment: Am I doomed? =D

Comment: No. You just need to save that first snippet as `something.pl`. Then use `perl` to run it. (The first line `#!/usr/bin/perl` should do that). You will _probably_ find that you need to also install `XML::Twig` (I'm guessing that because you've got `ksh` you're on `AIX`). This can be done by running: `perl -MCPAN -e shell` then `install XML::Twig`. (Or look at your package manager)

Comment: I am on read only =(