# How to implement awk range pattern in fetching an xml block when the input parameter is in the middle of the block

Tags: awk, ksh, xml

I am trying to fetch an xml block like this:

```
<machine name="sample1" min="1" max="10" idleTime="300" backend="ABC,XYZ">
                <handler className="com.abc.xyz.qwerty.foo.FooBar" />
                <details queue="ABC.SAMPLE" suggExpiry="30" minExpiry="4" maxExpiry="500"/>
                </machine>
```

details queue will be the input parameter.

I was successful when machine name (@ the start of the block)  was my parameter by using

```
awk '/<machine.*name="sample1"/,/<\/machine>/' Target.xml
```

How am I going to fetch the same xml block when the input parameter is the details queue (@ the middle of the block)?

Comment: Why do you want to process an XML file with `awk`?

Comment: 1. I cannot use any XML parser tool as I don't have permission , read only

2.     My xmllint version does not support xpath, and I cannot update it , read only

 3.   I dont have xmlstarlet and cannot install it

Comment: @Philip Morris; What versions/releases of `awk` do you have available?

Comment: @Janis
GNU Awk 3.1.5

Comment: Too bad; newer versions (4.x) of GNU awk would support XML parsing through the extension lib. Awk is not really well suited to do XML parsing in general; all you can to is solve the parsing through string processing and states. (See my answer below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one take on the issue with `awk`:

```
awk '
  /<machine.*name=/ { f=1 ; m=0 ; res="" }
  f { res = res $0 ORS }
  f && /PATTERN/ { m=1 }
  /<\/machine>/ { f=0 ; if (m) print res $0 }
' your_XML_file
```

It's implementing a FSA. Flag `f` controls whether you are in the desired XML block, flag `m` signal whether in that block your item had been found, and `res` is used to memorize the block, and will be printed at the end of a block if the conditions match.

Note that you have to replace `PATTERN` by the actual pattern you are looking for - in your sample it was, e.g., `<details queue="ABC.SAMPLE"` - which will be searched for between the opening and closing `<machine>` XML tags.

Answer (score 0):

Using `xmlstarlet` and providing the `queue` value on the command line as a parameter:

```bsh
xmlstarlet sel -t --var queue="'ABC.SAMPLE'"  -c \
    '//machine[details[@queue = $queue]]' -nl file.xml
```

This returns a copy of each and every `machine` node that has a `details` child-node with a `query` attribute with the value `ABC.SAMPLE`.