# Are there shells that supports typed variables and multidimensional arrays?

Tags: shell, variable

Is there a shell that supports distinguishing between variable types and multidimensional arrays?

At a minimum, it should distinguish between Strings, Integers, Floats and Doubles.

The following commands should be different. `command 1` and `command "1"` if variable types were supported. Notice it would be similar to a c function like `fun(1)` and `fun("1")`.  Alternatively it should have 2 separate syntaxes for shell and calling functions.

Comment: Bash can distinguish between strings and integers.

Comment: @muru True but not when passing arguments into a command.  In addition it only really supports 2 types Strings and Numbers, which is to narrow according to my question.

Comment: *integers, not numbers. Your question is about variables. Arguments to a command can be the content of variables, so I don't see what you mean by the first sentence.

Comment: @muru The following commands should be different.  `command 1` and `command "1"` if variable types were supported.  Notice it would be similar to a c function like `fun(1)` and `fun("1")`.

Comment: Well, if you recall your C, arguments are passed to `main` as strings, so irrespective of the shell, the arguments would become strings.

Comment: @muru Eventually but the  shell could convert the number into the appropriate Unicode character so it would be represented as a smaller/similar equivalent.  In addition isn't the reason `main` only supports strings because `shell`s have traditionally only supported Strings.  I'm still not certain how `Float`s would work.

Comment: Is that a fact? Anyway if it's the case that eventually they become strings, why should the shell take the trouble of parsing them?

Comment: @muru Again you could represent the Integer 65 as the character A.  Again it's to save space representing Integer's as String's is hardly efficient.

Comment: Maybe not efficient, but depending on the number in question, possibly with more precision. Should the shell have a bigint implementation as well  for, say, 2^90? Strings maybe inefficient, but they do offer the greatest freedom.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30366/discussion-between-liam-william-and-muru).

Comment: @mikeserv the Cygwin port of `mksh` doesn't appear to support multidimensional arrays.  For example the following fails `a=(1 (2 3))`.

Comment: mksh is not ksh93.

Comment: @mikeserv `mksh` is basically `ksh` although its not `ksh93`.  This leads me to believe it doesn't support multidimensional arrays.  http://www.kornshell.com/doc/ksh93.html http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#arrays

Comment: ksh93 supports multidimensional arrays. its like the only shell that truly does. it supports typed object multidimernsional arrays. it will even print them for you in json. mksh and ksh93 are very different things. mksh is the successor to pdksh, which was the only ksh you could get for free for decades until AT&T allowed Korn to publicly release it.  mksh is a lightweight shell w/ a ksh feel and is maintained by mirabilos in his free time. [`ksh93`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207125/52934) is [`ksh93`](http://www2.research.att.com/~astopen/download/gen/ast-ksh.html).

Comment: @mikeserv I'll roll it back the questions are quit similar though(I'm planning to leave multidimensional arrays because that was the original intent of the my question although it wasn't clear]).  I'm on Cygwin currently I'm limited on packages and testability.

Comment: cygwin sucks. but, since we're kind of one the subject, Korn's group is also responsible for [`UWIN`](http://www2.research.att.com/~astopen/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Perl Shell](https://gnp.github.io/psh/) supports three types of variables: scalars, lists, and hashes.

> Perl Shell (psh) combines aspects of bash and other shells with the power of Perl scripting.

and

> The Perl Shell is a shell that combines the interactive nature of a Unix shell with the power of Perl. The goal is to eventually have a  full featured shell that behaves as expected for normal shell activity.  But, the Perl Shell will use Perl syntax and functionality for control-  flow statements and other things.

It doesn't so much distinguish between Strings, Integers, Floats and Doubles*[1]*, as seamlessly convert between them as needed, exactly as Perl does.

It's difficult to see any reason why a shell would need to distinguish between a number `1` and the string `"1"` in any situation where auto-coversion was the Wrong Thing To Do, or where different operators for string vs numeric vs regexp comparison didn't suffice.  Much like `bash` or other shells do.

*[1]* See specialist modules like [Math::BigFloat](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.0/lib/Math/BigFloat.pm) if special handling of float types is required.  or [Math::Bigint](http://search.cpan.org/~pjacklam/Math-BigInt-1.999704/lib/Math/BigInt.pm) for very large integers.

Comment: finally! a question to which `psh` is an answer!!

Comment: Does this run on Windows?

Comment: no idea, i rarely use windows.  i would have thought that Powershell would be more appropriate on windows.

Comment: Why doesn't something like the following work `$test="test";echo $test`?  I don't see the advantage of perl if you can't pass variables as arguments.

Comment: what did i say that makes you think that?  it's certainly not true.

Comment: so how do I pass such floats or doubles to a shell command or work with multidimensional arrays?  That was kinda the intent of my question.

Comment: you pass them, as with every other argument, as strings.  it's up to the command to interpret them as floats or doubles.  perl (and thus psh) support multi-dimensional arrays.  as does ksh93.  BTW, you need to be much clearer in your thinking and your expression - you jumped straight from making an incorrect point about `$test="$test"` to "how do i pass such floats or doubles".  This may make some sense in your head but unless you take the time to clearly express all the intermediary steps in your thinking, it makes no sense to anyone else.

Comment: You misread my code it is `$test="test";echo $test`.  and then could you please post an example?

Comment: 1. an example of what? 2. you seem to have missed the point of my answer.   3. at the time I wrote the answer, there was no mention at all of multi-dimensional arrays in your question, but that now seems to have become the crucial focus. 4. I see no need to add an example or anything else to my answer, it said everything i wanted it to say.  5. If you have a new question about multi-dimensional arrays, you should ask a new question rather than arbitrarily change the scope of the original. 6. are you serious, or are you just trolling?

Comment: The original question was about variable types not specifically doubles and floats.  http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/236788/edit/439c0843-deb1-4608-aefa-2985d7d0d37f It just wasn't clear.  The following works in bash but not psh `$a=1;echo $a` it isn't really an improvement.

Comment: The following works `$t::a=1;echo $t::a` for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

There's a tension between having fine distinction between types and allowing quick typing. Shells are strongly geared towards quick typing: their purpose is to let you do once-off stuff easily, in as few characters as possible. Having to add quotes because you want `1` to be a string (to pass it to a program) rather than a number would be a burden.

Ksh, bash and zsh do have typed variables. However, these variables are just strings with extra validation. If you try to set an integer variable to a value that isn't an arithmetic expression, you'll get an error, or sometimes the value 0 (and in particular any valid identifier is replaced by 0 if it isn't a defined variable, unless `set -u` is in effect).

```
$ integer n
$ n=3
$ echo $n
3
$ n=2+2
$ echo $n
4
$ n=undefined+1
$ echo $n
1
$ n='_!@()#(*#'
mksh: _!@()#(*#: unexpected '!'
```

Ksh93 goes further and allows you to define custom types (with `typeset -T`), with functions to get and set variable values (called discipline functions) that allow you to reject invalid values. There's a predefined helper `enum` to define a type with a finite number of allowed values.

```
$ enum day=(Sunday Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday)
$ day d=Monday
$ echo $d
Monday
$ d=monday
ksh93: d:  invalid value monday
```

All values can be transparently used as strings though. If you don't want that, you automatically reduce the value of the language as a shell, because in the end the primary purpose of a shell is to run other programs, and a program's command line arguments are strings. However, there are interactive environments in which launching other programs is not considered the primary task, which don't have automatic conversion to strings. I list some in [Object-oriented shell for *nix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4495/object-oriented-shell-for-nix/4497#4497)

Comment: It doesn't appear multiple dimensional arrays are supported is that correct?  Also do you mind posting a `Double` and `Float` example?

Comment: Ksh93 and zsh have floats (`float x`), bash doesn't. You only get the maximum precision supported by the implementation (what C calls `double` or `long double`). When it comes to compound data structures, there are only arrays and string→string maps (which shells call associative array), in particular none give you nested arrays. Look at the documentation of the `typeset` builtin (`declare` in bash) to see what types each shell supports.