# How to extract data from a JSON file

Tags: text-processing, json

I have been searching for a solution for my question but didn't find a or better said I did not get it with what I found. 
My problem is:
I am using a Smart Home Control Software on a Raspberry Pi. 
Using [`pilight-receive`](https://manual.pilight.org/programs/receive.html),
I can capture the data from my outdoor temperature sensor. 
The output of pilight-receive looks like that:

```
{
        "message": {
                "id": 4095,
                "temperature": 409.5
        },
        "origin": "receiver",
        "protocol": "alecto_wsd17",
        "uuid": "0000-b8-27-eb-0f3db7",
        "repeats": 3
}
{
        "message": {
                "id": 1490,
                "temperature": 25.1,
                "humidity": 40.0,
                "battery": 1
        },
        "origin": "receiver",
        "protocol": "alecto_ws1700",
        "uuid": "0000-b8-27-eb-0f3db7",
        "repeats": 3
}
{
        "message": {
                "id": 2039,
                "temperature": 409.5
        },
        "origin": "receiver",
        "protocol": "alecto_wsd17",
        "uuid": "0000-b8-27-eb-0f3db7",
        "repeats": 4
}
```

Now my question is:
How the can I extract the temperature and humidity from messages where the id is 1490? 
And how would you recommend me to do check this frequently? 
By a cron job that runs every 10 minutes, creates an output of the `pilight-receive`,
extracts the data of the output and pushes it to the Smart Home Control API?

Comment: The format seems to be [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). There are plenty of ways to parse JSON. It depends on what you are comfortable with. Python? JavaScript? Something else?

Comment: I know a bit of Python and a bit of JavaScript mostly I know C++ and C#. But after seeing all the awk and sed commands I though the must be some easy command xD

Comment: It's not difficult with `awk` and `sed` provided the JSON output retains the formatting shown here, which it need not - whitespace doesn't matter for JSON. For example, this `awk` command: `awk '/temperature|humidity/ {print $2}'` is close.

Comment: with `ksh93` json parsing is builtin to [`read`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/207125/52934).

Comment: See my answer which simply uses `grep` and accomplishes the job just fine, with very little margin for error.

Comment: Wow I didn't expect that amount of answers. Thanks a lot to everybody. I will try the jq command posted by cas. Therefore I have to update my raspberry to Jessie, as the package is not available in wheezy. However I will do so tonight, to achieve my goal :)

Comment: check wheezy-backports.  it might be in there, saving you an upgrade to jessie (unless you were planning to upgrade anyway).  aha! it IS backported to wheezy.  https://packages.debian.org/wheezy-backports/jq

Comment: oh I didn't know something about this repo. I will definitly try it. Thanks in again :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use `jq` to process json files in shell.

For example, I saved your sample json file as `raul.json` and then ran:

```sh
$ jq .message.temperature raul.json 
409.5
25.1
409.5
$ jq .message.humidity raul.json 
null
40
null
```

[jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) is available pre-packaged for most linux distros.

There's probably a way to do it in `jq` itself, but the simplest way I found to get both the wanted values on one line is to use `xargs`.  For example:

```sh
$ jq 'select(.message.id == 1490) | .message.temperature, .message.humidity' raul.json | xargs
25.1 40
```

or, if you want to loop through each `.message.id` instance, we can add `.message.id` to the output and use `xargs -n 3` as we know that there will be three fields (id, temperature, humidity):

```sh
jq '.message.id, .message.temperature, .message.humidity' raul.json | xargs -n 3
4095 409.5 null
1490 25.1 40
2039 409.5 null
```

You could then post-process that output with awk or whatever.

---

Finally, both python and perl have excellent libraries for parsing and manipulating json data.  As do several other languages, including php and java.

Comment: specifically, `jq 'select(.message.id == 1490) | .message.temperature, .message.humidity' raul.json`

Comment: yep.  i've been trying to get jq to print them on one line.

Comment: `jq ... | paste -d " " - -`

Comment: or, in bash, `{ read temp; read hum; } < <(jq ...)`

Comment: See my answer which simply uses `grep`. It may not work for some specific versions of `grep`, but it's more straight-forward than `jq` in this scenario, even though `jq` is designed specifically for parsing JSON. I did give the `jq` answer an upvote though, regardless.  It is indeed a tool for the job, but sometimes you can simply remove staples with your fingers rather than searching around for a staple-remover.

Comment: json can't be reliably parsed with regular expressions any more than xml or html can.  and most json data (e.g. fetched via a web api) doesn't come nicely formatted with extra line-feeds and indentation.  to parse json reliably, you need a json parser.  `jq` is one such for shell scripts.  other languages have json parsing libraries.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone I will use your recommended jq command to achieve my goal.

Comment: anything can be reliably parsed with regular expressions. it just depends on how *many* you use. how do you think `jq` does it?

Comment: @mikeserv, no. not everything.  no matter how many you use.  jq does it with a lot more than just regular expressions.  a lexical grammar for example.  start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis

Comment: right, such as w/ the regex scanner `lex`?

Comment: the scanner is only a tiny part of a parser, and doesn't even necessarily use regexes (sometimes a scanf() is all that's needed).  by far the larger and more important part is the grammar which encodes an "understanding" of the language's symbols and syntax.  regexes "understand" nothing, they just search for patterns.

Comment: `lex`'s regular expression scanners are stateful. anyone implementing a scanner which does *not* take advantage of that fact is *wasting* a perfectly good resource. a regular expression isn't designed to *understand* anything - it is designed to find and extract.

Answer (score 1):

For those who don't understand advanced `awk` as well as they'd like to (such as people like me) and don't have `jq` pre-installed, an easy solution would be piping a couple of native commands together like so:

```
grep -A2 '"id": 1490,' stats.json | sed '/1490/d;s/"//g;s/,//;s/\s*//'
```

**If you're only trying to get the values, it's easier just using `grep` rather than `awk` or `sed`:**

```
grep -A2 '"id": 1490,' stats.json | grep -o "[0-9]*\.[0-9]*"
```

To provide an explanation, this seems like the simplest way to me.

- The `grep -A2` grabs the line you are looking for in the JSON along with the following 2 lines, which contain the temperature and humidity.
- The pipe to `grep -o` simply prints only numerical digits separated by a `.` (which will never occur on the first `1490` line, so you are left with your 2 values -- temperature and humidity.  Very simple. Even simpler than using `jq`, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

My tool of choice for processing JSON on the command line is jq. However, if you don't have jq installed you can do pretty well with Perl:

```
# perl -MJSON -e '$/ = undef; my $data = <>; for my $hash (new JSON->incr_parse($data)) { my $msg = $hash->{message}; print "$msg->{temperature} $msg->{humidity}\n" if $msg->{id} == 1490 }' < data.json
25.1 40
```

Answer (score 0):

`jq` is by far the most elegant solution. With `awk` you could write

```
awk -v id=1490 '
    $1 == "\"id\":" && $2 == id"," {matched = 1}
    $1 == "}," {matched = 0}
    matched && $1 ~ /temperature|humidity/ {sub(/,/,"", $2); print $2}
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

your output is a set of JSON snippets rather than a complete JSON. If / once you rearrange your output to be an integral JSON, e.g. like this (assuming your output is in `file.json`):

```
echo "[ $(cat file.json | sed -E 's/^}$/},/; $d') }]"
```

then it's easy to achieve what you want with `jtc` tool (available at: https://github.com/ldn-softdev/jtc):

```
bash $ echo "[ $(cat file.json | sed -E 's/^}$/},/; $d') }]" | jtc -x "[id]:<1490>d [-1]" -y[temperature] -y[humidity] -l
"temperature": 25.1
"humidity": 40.0
bash $
```

in the example above drop `-l` if you don't want printed labels

Answer (score 0):

To get the temperature and humidity from each message with `id` 1490, as a tab-delimited list, you may use

```bsh
jq -r '.message | select(.id == 1490) | [ .temperature, .humidity ] | @tsv'
```

Output given the data in the question:

```
25.1    40
```

To get CSV output, with the addition of a header, use

```bsh
jq -s -r '[ "temperature", "humidity" ], (.[] | .message | select(.id == 1490) | [ .temperature, .humidity ]) | @csv'
```

Note the added `-s` here to use `jq` in "slurp mode".  It reads all the objects in the input set into a single array and we use this to first give the `@csv` operator the CSV header as an array, and then a set of arrays containing the individual CSV records that we have extracted from the data.

Output given the data in the question:

```
"temperature","humidity"
25.1,40
```